# R: group_id by changing row values

Tags: r, group-by, grouping

1) Firstly, I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(value=c("a","a","a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a"), ,
                 desired_id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
```

How do I generate the `desired_id` column? 
My groups are assigned by row order.
That is, everytime the `value` column changes, I want the group indices to assign the next higher group indices.

I tried `df$desired_id_replicate <- df %>% group_by(value) %>% group_indices`
but that doesn't work as all `value=="a"` will be assigned the same group indices.

2)Secondly, I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(value=c("a","a","a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a"), 
                 value2=c("a","a","c", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d"),
                 desired_id=c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6))
```

How do I generate the `desired_id` from the `value` and `value2` column.
My groups are assigned row-wise again. That is, everytime a unique combination of `value` and `value2` changes, the next higher `desired_id` should be assigned.

Similar to the above, I tried `df$desired_id_replicate <- df %>% group_by(value, value2) %>% group_indices`
but that doesn't work as all `value=="a"&value2=="a"` will be assigned the same group indices.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rleid` (run-length-encoding id) from `data.table` which would basically increment 1 for each element that is not equal to the previous element

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  mutate(newcol = rleid(value))
```

and for the second dataset, it would be

```
df %>%
     mutate(new = rleid(value, value2))
#  value value2 desired_id new
#1     a      a          1   1
#2     a      a          1   1
#3     a      c          2   2
#4     b      b          3   3
#5     b      b          3   3
#6     b      c          4   4
#7     a      a          5   5
#8     a      a          5   5
#9     a      d          6   6
```

---

Or with `rle` from `base R`

```
df$newcol <- with(rle(df$value), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```